# ListView displaying items but not groups

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a simple modal dialog with a listview in it. When I add items as part of a group, the items will show up but the group headers will not. I've been trying with some dummy objects in the constructor. Here's that code:

```
    //Initialize and create columns
    public ConfirmDialog(List<ContentFileInfo> files, List<ContentFileInfo> folders, ManagerMain manager)
    {
        _myFiles = files;
        _myFolders = folders;
        _manager = manager;

        InitializeComponent();
        //cbFilter.SelectedIndex = 0;
        CreateColumns();

        lstChanges.BeginUpdate();
        lstChanges.ShowGroups = true;

        ListViewGroup test = new ListViewGroup("TestGroup");

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem {Group = test};
        ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem();
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem sub = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem sub2 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();

        sub.Text = "Item descrip.";
        sub2.Text = "Item2 descrip.";

        item.Text = "Item name.";
        item.SubItems.Add(sub);

        item2.Text = "Item2 name.";
        item2.SubItems.Add(sub2);

        lstChanges.Items.Add(item);
        lstChanges.Groups.Add(test);
        lstChanges.Items.Add(item2);

        lstChanges.EndUpdate();

        //GetAllFolders();
        //FillListByGroup();
        //NotifyOfUnchangedFiles();
    }
```

and here's the dialog as it appears during the session:
[image]

According to the debugger, everything is adding correctly:

[image]

And in case it helps, here's the code calling my dialog:

```
    //Event: Prompt user to approve change request
    private void btnPushChanges_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog(_cmprController.SelectedFiles, _cmprController.SelectedFolders, this);
        try
        {
            dialog.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems the VisualStyles is disabled for your application. You can enable it using [`Application.EnableVisualStyles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) in main method of your application class.

Comment: This did not solve it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` at the beginning of your application should help fix this. Read the remarks section of this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.showgroups(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ahh. When I read that, I assumed that it was only necessary to be called on those versions of Windows. I'm not sure why I thought that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

ListView [`Groups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) only show when visual styles are enabled for your application and it seems visual styles are disabled in your application.
To show groups in list view,
your application should call the [`Application.EnableVisualStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) method to enable visual styles for the application.
Typically, `EnableVisualStyles` is the first line in the `Main` method in `Program` class.