# ListViewGroup shows items but not headers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.8, listviewgroup

I have read through several forums and tried different options. Most of the answers were [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514095/15016928), which makes me assume that would be the issue. I placed `Application.EnableVisualStyles()`
at the beginning of `InitializeComponent()` in the *.Designer.vb* file as seen below:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class MetadataCollectionGUI
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles() '     <--- See Here
        Me.ListViewMetaDataCollection = New System.Windows.Forms.ListView()
        Me.ColumnTags = CType(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader(), System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)
        etc... etc...
    End Sub
    
    Etc...
    
End Class
```

---

Did I misunderstand how to execute that particular solution or is the issue something different?

Comment: Think you need to move that up the callstack somewhere.  As mentioned in the link, it's typically done in first thing in your application main.  Inside the form such as this may be too late

Comment: Firstly, as the comment states, you should not be editing that `InitializeComponent` method. Unless you're actually fixing something that the designer should have done itself, the next time you make a change in the designer, any manual code changes you made will be lost.

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do makes no sense anyway. The link you provided is for C#, where you always need your own `Main` method. In VB projects, the Application Framework is enabled by default, which hides the `Main` method from you in auto-generated code, and visual styles are also enabled by default. Take a look at your project properties and enable visual styles there if they are not currently. If they already are then you're trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist. Please add a screenshot of your `ListView` so we can see whether visual styles are enabled.

Comment: Ah, thank you @jmcilhinney. I did not know C# was that different from VB. I am learning things as I go so I was not aware that VB hides the `Main` method. I just assumed that since my project starts up with my form and I was unable to locate the `Main`, it just did not exist. I am not sure what you mean by a screenshot of the `ListView`. Did you need to see the properties window, the .designer.vb code, or the GUI? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't need to see anything now, but I meant a a screenshot of the control at run time. If we could see the control, we could tell whether visual styles were enabled or not.

Comment: Ohh, ok thank you for clarifying and thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was. Go to the project properties and enable the application framework. Now you can enabled the XP visual styles.

[image]

---

Thank you Hursey & jmcilhinney, I would not have figured it out without you all!

Comment: It's worth noting that those two boxes are checked by default in a new project. If the visual styles box was unchecked in your project then I can only assume that you unchecked it at some point. I don't recall but it may be that, in some early version of VS, the visual styles box was unchecked by default so, if your project was originally created in that version, you may not have unchecked it explicitly. That said, your project targets NetFx 4.8 so either it was created recently or you've opened that property page at least once, so you should have known what other options were available.

Comment: I thought it was enabled by default. I almost even commented about it, but felt it would not be important enough to include to the post. I originally started this project in Net 5.0, but it wouldn't run on any of the other computers, since they did not have the latest ms packages/versions, so I copied it over to a new 4.8 version and must have accidently disabled it during setup. Anyway, thank you again!